# Return variable from class to MainForm

Tags: c#, return

I have section in my class that looks like this:

```
public Details GetTicketById(string @ref)
{
    var query = "SELECT * FROM support WHERE ref = @ref";

    var args = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"@ref", @ref}
    };

    DataTable dt = ExecuteRead(query, args);

    if (dt == null || dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var details = new Details
    {
        @ref = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["ref"]),
        subject = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["subject"]),
        contact_name = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["contact_name"]),
        company_name = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["company_name"]),
        description = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["description"]),
        business_impact = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["business_impact"]),
        severity = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["severity"])
    };


    return details;
}
```

I know that there is a return value when I debug.

My button in my main form looks like this:

```
private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var getTicket = new ticket();

    getTicket.GetTicketById("1235");

    ticket.Details td = new ticket.Details();

    td.@ref = txtRef.Text;
    td.subject = txtSubject.Text;
    td.contact_name = txtContact_Name.Text;
    td.company_name = txtCompany_Name.Text;
    td.description = rtDescription.Text;
    td.business_impact = rtBusiness_Impact.Text;
    td.severity = txtSeverity.Text;
}
```

Unfortunately my text boxes do not show the values from my returned data table.

Can you see why?

Comment: Let's say that `new ticket()` is instance of your class with method `GetTicketById()`. It return value, but you don't take it. Change like this: `var details = getTicket.GetTicketById("1235");` And now set `Text` property like this `txtSubject.Text = details.subject` and so on

Comment: also looks like you assign textbox.Text to your td.properties instead of "txtBox.Text = td.@ref"...

Comment: @Viewed: you were correct, you can add your answer and I will accept that, thank you!

Comment: @merkithuseyin: yes sir you were correct also! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `GetTicketById()` return value like you and see with debug. But you don't take this value into variable. Do this:

```
var details = getTicket.GetTicketById("1235");
```

In order to set `Text` property to new value do this:

```
txtSubject.Text = details.subject
txtContact_Name.Text = details.contact_name
txtCompany_Name.Text = details.company_name
// and so on
```

This line need to delete

```
ticket.Details td = new ticket.Details();
```